# Error installing XercesC with MinGW

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw, xerces-c

I'm trying to build XercesC-3.1.2 with MinGW.

After running `$ mingw32-make` in the xerces directory, I get the following error:

```
mingw32-make[4]: Entering directory '/my/path/to/xerces-c-3.1.2/src'
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, /bin/mkdir -p xercesc/util, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Following the [XercesC build instructions](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/build-3.html), I'm running the `configure` script as

```
$ ./configure CC=mingw32-gcc CXX=mingw32-g++
```

but without the variable `LDFLAGS=-no-undefined`. This is contrary to the build instructions in the XercesC webpage because otherwise the configure script will not work because the flag is not recognized by gcc. The `configure` script seems to run fine, however. After that, running `mingw32-make` gives the error above.

My mingw32-make and mingw32-gcc versions are

- mingw32-gcc/g++ 4.8.1
- mingw32-make 3.82.90

I tried adding `C:\MinGW\libexec\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1` to my `PATH`, [as suggested by Codeblocks](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_MinGW_with_Vista), but had no exit.

I also fresh installed MinGW in another machine that has no other compiler (or Cygwin, or anything) and got the same results.

Comment: Are you sure it's xerces-c-3.2.1 that you are trying to build? The build instructions, to which you refer, would seem to be for xerces-c-3.1.2, (which appears to be the currently released version).

Comment: The xerces-c build system will not allow you to create a DLL, without `LDFLAGS=-no-undefined`; this is implicit, and therefore quite redundant, when building Windows DLLs, so I consider the need to specify it explicitly to be a build system bug. This is further exacerbated by its misuse within the configure script, (causing `configure` to abort with a _"compiler cannot create executables"_ exception; however, it is possible to specify it _after_ running `configure`, as a macro specification when invoking `make`.

Comment: Yes, @KeithMarshall, xerces-c-3.1.2, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using MSYS to run the configure script, so why are you using `mingw32-make` for the `make` step?  You should run the `make` step in MSYS too, and use the `make` which is provided with MSYS.  The error message which you see suggests that `mingw32-make` is unable to resolve the path to `/bin/mkdir`, which is an MSYS command, and should not be visible outside the MSYS shell process context.

FWIW, `xerces-c-3.1.2` builds OOTB for me, cross-compiling with gcc-4.9.3 and binutils-2.24.1, as follows:

```
tar xf ~/Downloads/xerces-c-3.1.2.tar.xz
mkdir xerces-c-3.1.2/build
cd xerces-c-3.1.2/build
../configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --enable-static --enable-shared
...
make LDFLAGS=-no-undefined
make prefix=`pwd`/dist/staged install
```

Comment: Thanks @KeithMarshall Your solution worked. 

I'm new to MinGW and I didn't know there was this difference between `make` and `mingw32-make`.

The reason why I was trying to use `mingw32-make` is because I was doing that in Cygwin first, and I wanted to make sure that I was compiling with MinGW and not for Cygwin. It seems that I will not need to use Cygwin after all.

Comment: You _can_ use Cygwin, @FKaria, just as I use Linux as _my_ build platform. You would need to adjust the `--build=...` and `--host=...` options to the `configure` script, to match whatever is appropriate for the Cygwin to MinGW cross environment; (I can't help you with that). Thereafter, you would use Cygwin's `make` to complete the build, using whatever cross-compiler was identified by `configure`.